# Why the INOUT doesn't work?

Tags: hardware, vhdl

I am making a circuit that handles read and write operations to some registers and uses a single bus to transfer data between registers, the problem is that when reading from bus (a register is reading from bus) it works well, but when trying to assign a value in a register it is not working. Note that if i used a signal to write to it will work !!!

My Code:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE     IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Entity: Circuit
-- Description: Organizes read and write operation to the bus
-- n is the size of word in a register, default is 16
-- m is the number of selection lines in the decoder, so 2 ^ m
-- is the number of registers in the cicuit

-- data_bus: the bus used to transfer data
-- reg_read: input to a decoder determines which register to read from bus.
-- reg_write: input to a decoder determines which register to write to bus.
-- read: read signal
-- write: write signal
-- Clk: clock
-- Rst: Reset

ENTITY circuit IS
  GENERIC( n : integer := 16; 
           m : integer := 2);
  PORT(data_bus : INOUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 DOWNTO 0);
       reg_read, reg_write : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(m-1 DOWNTO 0);
       read, write, Clk, Rst : IN STD_LOGIC);

END circuit;


ARCHITECTURE circuit_arch OF circuit IS

-- Tristate buffers
COMPONENT tsb IS
  GENERIC ( n : integer := 16);

  PORT ( E   : IN  STD_LOGIC; 
         Input  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 DOWNTO 0);
         Output : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT;


-- Registers
COMPONENT ndff IS
  GENERIC ( n : integer := 16);
  PORT( Clk,Rst,E : in STD_LOGIC;
        d : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 dOWNTO 0);
        output : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 dOWNTO 0));

END COMPONENT;

-- Decoders
COMPONENT nDecoder IS
  GENERIC ( n : integer := 4);
  PORT(E : IN std_logic;
       S : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( n-1 DOWNTO 0);
       output : OUT std_logic_vector(2 ** n - 1 DOWNTO 0));

END COMPONENT;

TYPE output IS ARRAY (0 TO (2 ** m) - 1) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL read_dec, write_dec : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 ** m - 1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL regs_out : output;
SIGNAL test : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
BEGIN


  -- Generate decoders
  dec1: nDecoder GENERIC MAP(m) PORT MAP(read, reg_read, read_dec);
  dec2: nDecoder GENERIC MAP(m) PORT MAP(write, reg_write, write_dec); 

   -- Generate registers
  LOOP1: FOR i IN 0 TO (2 ** m) - 1 GENERATE

    lbl1: ndff GENERIC MAP(n) PORT MAP(Clk, Rst,read_dec(i),data_bus, regs_out(i));

  END GENERATE;

  -- Generate tristate buffers
  LOOP2: FOR j IN 0 TO (2 ** m) - 1 GENERATE

    lbl2: tsb GENERIC MAP(n) PORT MAP(write_dec(j), regs_out(j), data_bus);

  END GENERATE;

END circuit_arch;
```

Comment: Add the entity/arch for "tsb".

Comment: What is the target platform for your design? (FPGA, ASIC, Xilinx, Altera, Virtex, Stratix, ...)

Comment: Seeing as how you haven't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) perhaps you'd show us waveforms that tell you it isn't working? "Note that if i used a signal to write to it will work !!!" seems very ambiguous. It doesn't describe methodology and connectivity.

Comment: i was trying to desgin an internal bus in PDP-11 processor for learning purposed the solution is to no force the "databus" object before write to bus. the code is correct. thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `lbl1` in the generate statement you'll find the portmap:

```
 lbl1: ndff generic map(n) port map(clk, rst,read_dec(i),data_bus, regs_out(i));
```

is positionally associative. While the port declaration reflected in the component declaration shows the order:

```
port( clk,rst,e : in std_logic;
        d : in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
        output : out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0));
```

Showing that `read_dec(i)` is the register load enable.

And the read buffers:

```
  -- generate tristate buffers
  loop2: for j in 0 to integer(2 ** m) - 1 generate

    lbl2: tsb generic map(n) port map(write_dec(j), regs_out(j), data_bus);

  end generate;
```

Show `write_dec(j)`.

And examining the decodes for generating them shows:

```
  -- generate decoders
  dec1: ndecoder generic map(m) port map(read, reg_read, read_dec);
  dec2: ndecoder generic map(m) port map(write, reg_write, write_dec);
```

`read` corresponds to `read_dec` and `write` corresponds to `write_dec`.

It certainly looks like you have the enables reversed for the registers loads and register output buffer enables.

There could be more, but without a MVCE someone answering can't get beyond basic eyeballing and analyzing.

And the reason Paebbels asked about target implementation is that for all practical purposes tristate internal buffers are generally restricted to ASIC implementations.

Comment: This was my intention :) ... but it's also possible to use internal  INOUT signals in 'FPGAs' (in synthesis compilers for FPGAs) if certain requirements are met.

Comment: This looks like a natural place for an output selector.